# Perform string manipulation on a value and return the original JSON document with jq

Tags: json, jq

In my JSON document I have a string that I need manipulated and then have the entire document returned with the 'fixed' values.

The input document is:

```
{
    "records" : [
            {
                "time": "123456789000"

            },
            {
                "time": "123456789000"
            }

    ]
}
```

I want to find the "time" key and replace the string by dropping off the last 3 chars. The resulting document would be:

```
{
    "records" : [
            {
                "time": "123456789"

            },
            {
                "time": "123456789"
            }

    ]
}
```

I've been trying to understand the jq query syntax but I'm not coming right. I'm still struggling to return the whole document when filtering on a specific value. All I have so far is:

```
.records[] | select(.time | contains("123456789000"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using `|=` and [string slicing](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/StringSlice:.[10:15])

```
.records[].time |= .[:-3]
```

Sample Run (assuming data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -M '.records[].time |= .[:-3]' data.json
{
  "records": [
    {
      "time": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "time": "123456789"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/VzYkL1HfnY)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With **jq** **`sub()`** function:

```
jq '.records[].time |= sub("[0-9]{3}$";"")' file
```

The output:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "time": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "time": "123456789"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Or even simpler: via dividing the `time` value by `1000`:

```
jq '.records[].time |= (tonumber / 1000 | tostring)' file
```

Comment: Using `tonumber` without `tostring` will of course result in a number :-)

Comment: @peak, once again )

Comment: Using `sub`, `...$` should suffice as a simpler regular expression; the original question doesn't seem to indicate that only a subset of `time` values should be trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

The following works with jq version 1.4 or later:

```
jq '.records[].time |= .[:-3]' file.json
```

(The expression `.[:-3]` is short for `.[0:-3]`; the negative integer here counts from the right.)

With jq 1.3, the following filter would work in your particular case:

```
.records[].time |= (tonumber | ./1000 | tostring)
```

Comment: I'm surprised. Looks like my jq version at work is quite outdated. I was trying that this afternoon but got "cannot index string with integer".

Comment: Is it the ability to index strings with numbers or the update assignment operator which is new in jq-1.4? In the latter case I might just had a typo this afternoon and would delete my answer because that's what I really wanted to do and I'm using the update assignment operator anyway.

Comment: jq 1.3 does not support slicing a string, e.g. `jq1.3 -n '"abc" | .[0:-1]'` yields:
jq: error: Cannot index string with object

Comment: jq 1.3 does not even have join/1 or explode/0 !

Comment: Like I said, I was also surprised. I'm pretty sure that I have jq-1.5 at work. Looks like I just did something wrong.